# error in .shp and .dbf files

Tags: r

http://web1.sph.emory.edu/users/lwaller/ch9index.htm

I'm getting error for .shp and .dbf files

> library(maptools) scot_mp <- readShapeSpatial('C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/New Scot/scot.shp')
>
> Error in read.dbf(filen1) : unable to open DBF file

sorry sir, im getting this error,can you please help me,i copied same folder as scot.shp,scot.dbf,scot.shx, bt still im getting this error

> scot_mp <- readShapeSpatial('C:/Documents and Settings/Admin/Desktop/scotlip/lip cancer/new scot1/scot.shp')
> Error in getinfo.shape(fn) : Error opening SHP file

Comment: Did you try to read the shapefile using the `readOGR` function from the `rgdal` package?

Comment: s i tried readOGR function with rgdal package..i cant execute

Answer (score 1):

If your DBF file is named with a `.dbf` extension, try renaming it to `.DBF`. In other words, capitalize the extension name.